# Текстовый редактор html совместимый с AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, редактор-текста

Делаю сайт, на нем есть форма ввода. Ввод формы сделан на AngularJS версии 1. Для одного из полей нужно подключить визуальный текстовый редактор, чтобы пользователь мог форматировать описание. Кто нибудь может подсказать какой нибудь редактор, который будет совместим с AngularJS? Раньше я использовал ckeditor, но с AngularJS при использовании в этом поле ng-model он не работает.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант

---

## textAngular

[живой пример](http://textangular.com/)

Как использовать:

1. Include `textAngular.js` in your project, или возьмите весь этот код и поместите `"directives.js"` модуль.
2. Include textAngular in your main app module.
3. Добавте любой эллемент, возможно `div`, это не имеет значения.
4. Добавте в него директиву `text-angular`.
5. И директиву `text-angular-name="<YOUR TEXT EDITOR NAME>"`.

А дальше вам необходимо создать объект и правильно его настроить, привязать контроллер, поиграться с его тулбаром...

[смотрите в документации](http://ngmodules.org/modules/textAngular)

Comment: Скачал архив, в корне файла textAngular.js нет, подключил следующие файлы из папки dist: textAngular.css,textAngular-rangy.min.js,textAngular-sanitiz‌​e.min.js,textAngular‌​.min.js. Вписал в зависимости своего контроллера $textAngular начала появляться ошибка : angular.min.js:118 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/unpr?p0=textAngularProvider